# Configure WiFi router DHCP to assign IPs outside of subnet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, bridge

I have a slightly unusual issue with configuring a Wifi router on a shared office space network:

We have a single ethernet connection to a building wide router `A` and we want to run a WiFi access point `B` for multiple devices `C`, `D`, `E`. As I understand it, the normal way to do this is for the router to host a local subnet, and assign arbitrary IPs to those devices. As far as the upstream router `A` is concerned, all traffic from `C`, `D` and `E` is actually coming from `B`'s IP.

However, the upstream router `A` has a hard limit on the number of concurrent connections (to prevent torrenting, presumably), so configuring it this way means `C`, `D` and `E`'s connections regularly drop out.

To workaround the issue, we need to ensure that devices `C`, `D`, and `E` appear as unique IPs on `A`'s subnet. As far as I can tell, the only way to achieve this is to configure `B`'s DHCP to assign IPs it doesn't actually manage - IPs that are not in a subnet it owns.

Is this possible with a consumer-grade router, and what is this sort of configuration called?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have explained is called bridge configuration. The WLAN access point must be configured to act as a bridge.

I cannot tell you if this is possible with your device as you have not written which WLAN device you have.

This is possible with consumer devies as e.g. the Fritz!Box from AVM (a german brand) has the possibility to switch between bridge and router mode.